# Delay time between transactions

Tags: timer, jmeter

I have a JMeter script which has multiple Transaction controllers and each Transaction controllers have multiple samples. I want to implement 5 secs delay time between each transaction controllers. What is the right approach?

The script has n number of Threads.

Comment: I've added the jmeter tag to your question - you should almost always add a language tag to help others to categorise your question without having to click on it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "`Constant Timer`" after each "`Transaction Controller`" by giving delay of 5 sec.It is a simplest and easy approach for that.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add constant timer/Uniform random timer of 5 sec only in first sample of each transaction controller (no need to include in first sample of first transaction controller)[image]